# How to mock variable's value within the function that I want to test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I want to write a test for the function `computePrice` within the `Data` class.

```
public static double ComputePrice (double a) 
{
    double c = Config.Instance.example1;
    double d = Config.Instance.example2;
    double result = 0;
    result = c * d + a;
    return result;
}
```

The `Config.Instance.example1` and `Config.Instance.example2` are the 2 fields where users can set in the UI configuration page, the related code is below:

```
public class Config
{
    private static Lazy<Config> _Instance = new Lazy<Config>()... //obmitted
    public static Config Instance { get { return _Instance.Value;} }
    
    [Category("params")]
    [XmlAttribute("example1")]
    public double example1 { get; set; }
    
    [Category("params")]
    [XmlAttribute("example2")]
    public double example2 { get; set; }
}
```

In my test, I currently have something like:

```
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void TestComputePrice()
    {
        //Arrange
        double a = 1
        //Act
        double testedResult = Data.ComputePrice(a);
        
        Assert.AreEqual(3, testedResult);
    }
}
```

However, the issue is that when computing `ComputePrice(a)` with the test, the `Config.Instance.example1` and `Config.Instance.example2` will be defaulted to 0.

I am not sure how should I "mock" the values of the variables, i.e. `Config.Instance.example1` and `Config.Instance.example2` which will be used in the `ComputePrice` function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406959/5045688

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't. This is one of the reasons why a singleton class is often preferable to a static class in C#.

One workaround to achieve what you want is to create a wrapper non-static class and interface that would provide the `GetExample1()` and `GetExample2()` methods. The implementation of this wrapper class can use the static values under the hood. Then you register the wrapper class as the implementation of the interface via DI, inject the interface into the class where `ComputePrice` lives and replace the direct references to `example1` and `example2` in the code to the calls of these methods. You will also have to make these methods non-static too, if you want them to be testable. This will look like this:

```
public interface IConfigWrapper
{
  double GetExample1();
  double GetExample2();
}

public class ConfigWrapper: IConfigWrapper
{
  public ConfigWrapper() {}
  public double GetExample1() => Config.Instance.example1;
  public double GetExample2() => Config.Instance.example2;
}

// In your Startup.cs or Program.cs
...
  builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigWrapper, ConfigWrapper>();
...

// In the class where ComputePrice method belongs

public class SomePriceComputingClass
{
  private readonly IConfigWrapper _configWrapper;
  public SomePriceComputingClass(IConfigWrapper wrapper)
  {
    _configWrapper = wrapper;
  }
  ...
  public double ComputePrice (double a) 
  {
    double c = _configWrapper.example1;
    double d = _configWrapper.example2;
    double result = 0;
    result = c * d + a;
    return result;
  }  
}
```

After all this setup, you will be able to use e.g. `Moq` to mock the wrapper class as needed.

Comment: but the `Config` class *is* a singleton, not a static class.... if it was injected into the class that contains the `static double ComputePrice(double a)` class, and it's injected as an interface and not as a class, then it's just as simple as any other mock. Question is, should `ComputePrice` really be a static method?

Comment: Since `Data` is a static class, after changing `ComputePrice` to non static method there'll be a warning `static class cannot have non static method`, may I ask if it is true that to test this `ComputePrice`, the only way we can do it is to create a wrapper non-static class? In such case it may seem it's too much trouble than it worth. Maybe it's better for me to do manual testing in such case? Thank you

Comment: @w97802 the question is, **why** is `Data` a static class? is it the proper design for it?