# Unit test extension with private class

Tags: unit-testing, model-view-controller, nsubstitute

I have a code like this that I need to unit test but I can't manage to get inside `options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` part of code. How should I do that?

```
public IMvcBuilder Customize(this IMvcBuilder services)
{
  serivces.ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => 
     options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
     { 
        
       .... call for some private method
     return BadRequestResult();
     }
return services;
}
```

I've tried to make a substitute for options, set isValid as false etc. but nothing worked. I have no idea what to try next.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406959/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov well I can't add any new framework to this project.

Comment: You can, I believe in you. | These frameworks are for testing purposes only. They will not affect your working project in any way.

Comment: That's not the point. I have a list of frameworks that client allows to use. I can't add anything there.

Comment: The client will never know what you are using for testing, development, debugging. Because the IDE, profiler, debugger, test framework - all this remains with you, the client will not see them.

Comment: If you want to use NSubstitute, then you must completely rewrite the code. Because this library can mock only virtual methods.