# How to mock an object thats not passed in constructor & Initialized in constructor with new()?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a httpRequest Class that does facilitates httpCommunication. Now I wanted to add a cert to the httpclient in that class. So I created another constructor which adds the certificate to the httpClient member of the clas. So my class with new ctor look like this.

```
class HttpRestClient: IHttpRestClient
{
   private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
    public HttpRestClient(
               IService1 configuration,
               IService2 appAssignmentsContext
               )
            {
                this.httpContextHelper = contextAccessor;
                this.appAssignmentsContext = appAssignmentsContext;
                this.tokenProvider = GetTokenProvider();
                this.httpClientHandler = GetHttpClientHandler(configuration);
    
                var cert = tokenProvider.GetMyCert();
                httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
                
                this.httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
            }
}
```

Now there is a class that uses this constructor

```
 class MynewClass: IMynewInterface
    {
    private IService1 service1;
    private IService2 service2;
    private IHttpRestClient client;
    public MynewClass(Iservice1 service1, Iservice2 service2, IHttpRestClient restclient)
    {
     this.service1= service1;
     this.service2 = service2;
     this.client = new HttpRestClient(service1, service2);
    }
    }
public void MyMethod(){
// Validation logic
return client.GetData(url);
}
```

Since I am just initi8alizing the object in constructor How do I mock the GetData Method?
or should the caller of `MynewClass` provide the IHttpRestclient object as `new HttpRestClient(service1, service2)` and I simply assign it in the `MynewClass` ctor?

Any better way to write the code unit test friendly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406959/5045688

Comment: The provided code doesn't reflect the information from your question. What are `httpRequest` and `httpCommunication`? The `MynewClass` receives `IHttpRestClient` in the constructor but also creates a `new HttpRestClient`. Please update the code and the question so they explain each other.  But in general, you can't mock an object that is not controlled in the test code. You need to follow the Inversion Of Control principle to be able to mock dependencies.