# Moq Setup statement for LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, moq

I am writing unit tests in C# using Moq framework. I would like to write a setup statement for the following line of code :

```
var myFile = (FileTarget) LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("file");
```

How can I do this since without writing one I get the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

I was trying to write it as follows:

```
var logObject = new Mock<LogFactory>();
```

But, when I debug my code I get the error: Unsupported expression.Non-overridable members may not be used in setup / verification expressions. I am not able to find the corresponding interface to mock this either. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to create your own interface and wrap the static type, then you can mock your own interface.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406959/5045688

Comment: I have not injected the interface into my main method and not replaced the original method with the one I defined in my interface. Is it necessary to do so? Or can I use my method to setup the statement but keep the original code as is. Kindly advise. Thank you.