# Duplication in unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, composition

Lets say I have a class like the following :

```
public class Component
{
    private readonly object _a;
    private readonly object _b;
    private readonly object _c;

    public object OperationX() => new object();
    public object OperationY() => new object();

    public Component(object a, object b, object c)
    {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
        _c = c;
    }
}
```

I can write unit tests for `OperationX()` and `OperationX()`, which is all good.

Now, I want to use this `Component` in another class like so :

```
public class TypeA
{
    private Component _component;

    public object A() => _component.OperationX();
    public object B() => _component.OperationY();

    public TypeA()
    {
        _component = new Component(new object(), new object(), new object());
    }
}
```

This class essentially forwards the work of `A()` and `B()` to the `Component` class. Although it just forwards the work, I still want to write tests to make sure that the results of `A()` and `B()` are the expected results. For example, `A()` and `B()` could be virtual, and I may have accidently forgotten to override them, or they may have gotten broken during a merge. So it's important they're tested.

If I was to write tests for  `A()` and `B()`, I would essentially be duplicating the tests I wrote for `Component`?

I find myself doing a lot of this duplication in my tests, because I use a composition a lot, and I'm not sure if it's good or bad?

What if I create another class that forwards methods to an instance of `TypeA`? now I will be duplicated the same tests a third time.

I suppose I could have `Component` have an interface and be injected into `TypeA`, so then I can mock it, and test that `OperationX()` is being called, instead of actually testing the result. But to me that has downsides :

- Every creation of `Component` now needs to pass in new instance of `Component`. So now I've made the calling coding messier for the sake of testing.
- `Component` is a very small object, and seems overkill to be included in dependency injection

Comment: The correct way is to use the interface and dependency injection. / Is it C#? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406959/5045688 Try some unconstrained mocking framework.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov yes, I get why that helps to solve the testing problem. But it then feels like I've just exposed something that is really an implementation detail, just for the sake of being able to test it.

Comment: I think this would fit better on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com than here, as it's more about the *design* of the system than the *implementation*. See [Software Engineering on-topic list](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) vs [Stack Overflow on-top list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should treat your [system under test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) like a black box as much as you can.

The fact that `TypeA` relies on `Component` to perform it's job is an **implementation detail that should not leak into your tests**. That could change in the future, for instance you may decide to get rid of `Component` and integrate its code inside `TypeA`, or you may decide to split `Component` in two different classes.

So from this point of view, I'd say it's not incorrect to somehow duplicate the   assertions that you perform for the tests of `Component` and `TypeA`.

---

However, if you find yourself doing again and again this kind of duplication I'd say there might be a design problem in your classes. You say that you are using composition, but **the functionality provided by the "inner types" should not be the same as the functionality provided by the "outer types"** (those composing the "inner types").

It can happen that your "outer type" simply forwards to the inner one, for instance if it acts as a [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), but this should be rare.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with your first point. It is entirely an implementation detail that I do not want to expose via constructor injection, which is why I feel that the duplicated tests kind of make sense (but wasn't sure). As for your second point, rightly or wrongly, I do tend to do this a lot. For example, I might have several different classes that all serialise the same way, but for whatever reason cannot use inheritance. So instead, they each have an instance of the class that does the serialisation, which is forwarded to through a public method. Would you say that is bad practise?