# In c# how should I test a static method that use inside a singleton?

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I need to test MyMethodToTest but it call a method that use inside a singleton

```
public static string MyMethodToTest()
{
    int a = 4 * 9;
    string b = GetSomething()
    return b + a.ToString();
}
  
public static string GetSomething()
{
    return MySingleton.Instance.GetString();
}
```

I tried with monkey patching but without and result and with Dependency Injection could be problematic because is static

Comment: Write the setup for the MySingleton.Instance field/property in a way to be replaceable?

Comment: You're discovering why people tend to avoid singletons!

Comment: _Unconstrained_ mocking frameworks can help. Here list of them https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406959/5045688

Comment: If you have control over the codebase, consider refactoring it to be more testable. This might involve reducing the reliance on singletons or static methods, or breaking down complex methods into smaller, more testable components.
Remember that aiming for testable code often leads to better code design and maintainability. While testing code with heavy dependencies like singletons can be challenging, applying the principles of decoupling, dependency injection, and seam-based techniques can help you achieve more effective testing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an inherent problem with singletons.

There are a few ways to approach this.

#### Make singletons immutable

Singletons are problematic since they represent global shared state. But if the state never changes, or if the singleton only represent behavior, most of the problems disappear. So you can just write tests using the known value or behavior.

#### Make the singleton an input variable

Write your method as

```
public static string MyMethodToTest(this IMySingleton self)
```

This allow you to replace the singleton with a mock for testing.

#### Use dependency injection instead of static

Dependency injection allow you to declare an instance as a singleton *for a given context*, or container, instead of program wide. This is inherently more flexible. It should also solve your testing problem since you can just replace the singleton in the container. But it may require architectural changes if your program is not already designed using DI.