# Mocking a constructor called from the sut

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a service I'm trying to test which has this code in it:

```
public async Task ExecuteAsync()
{
    IEnumerable<Dto> dtos = await _injectedDtoBuilder.CreateAsync(_injectedParameters);

    foreach (Dto dto in dtos)
    {
        DataEntity dataEntity = new DataEntity(dto);

        await _injectedRepository.AddAsync(dataEntity);
    }
}
```

`DataEntity`'s constructor has its own tests, I don't need to test it again here. It's also very complicated - the DTO is pretty enormous - and I don't want to have to set up all that test data. All the injected parameters and services can be mocked with Moq no problem, but I can't see a good way to unit test this in isolation from `DataEntity`, nor any sensible way to rewrite it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which behavior should the test verify? If you mock `_injectedDtoBuilder`, `DataEntity`, and `_injectedRepository`, then what are you actually testing?

Comment: About the only thing I can think of to test is to verify that `_injectedRepository.AddAsync()` is called the correct number of times (in the unstubbed code, `_injectedDtoBuilder` actually returns an `IEnumerable<Dto>`, and the `DataEntity` constructor and `_injectedRepository.AddAsync()` are inside a `foreach` loop). But we have code coverage requirements to meet, so...

Comment: `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` for things that do not need testing?

Comment: Inject some mapper and use it: `DataEntity dataEntity = _myMapper.CreateDataEntity(dto);`. Now you can mock mapper.

Comment: Another approach: use _unconstrained_ mocking framework. Here I have listed them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406959/5045688