# Shim a class being called in base class in c#

Tags: c#

I have a Test Class

```
[TestClass]
Public class PMTestClass
{
   private readonly SHTest shtest= new SHTest();
}
//Another class
public class SHTest : SHbase
{
    public SHTest:base()
    {
    }
}
//Another class
public abstract class SHbase : ISHbase
{
    //There is some other class here which I want to shim. How can i do that?
}
```

When I debug a Test method in PMTest class instead of the original class in the SHbase I want the shimmed class to be executed. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406959/5045688 Use one of the unconstrained frameworks

Comment: Microsoft supports this with Shims, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-shims-to-isolate-your-application-from-other-assemblies-for-unit-testing?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp