# Moq static class in unit test, Xunit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-6.0, xunit, xunit.net

I added dll  reference's of another project, I used xunit, I want to moq the functions of it, like this code

```
public bool Test(string value)
 {
   // using ACPUtilityManager.HelperUtility: ACPUtilityManager is reference of another project librairy  
   // WebServiceUtility: static class , testMoq(value)  method of this class  
     var ttt = WebServiceUtility.testMoq(value);
    
     return true;
 }
```

but i can't moq this a class, help me please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406959/5045688

Comment: hi @AlexanderPetrov, thanks but it does not work

Comment: It's work. Dixi.

Comment: you can give me an example, please.

Comment: Choose any library and read the docs. For example, [AutoFake](https://github.com/Serg046/AutoFake).