# Mocking internal class without interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit, internal-class

I am trying to mock internal class for unit tests, due to some circular dependency I will not be able to use interface of this class to mock it, I also added unit test assembly name (made sure I am using correct assembly name from properties) to AssemblyInfo.cs of this project with InternalsVisibleTo , also added AssemblyInfo to csproj using `<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />`, this makes class visible to test file but its not visible for mocking

> **NotSupportedException**: Type to mock must be an interface, a delegate, or a non-sealed, non-static class.

I want to create mock of this class to do setup on other method in this class which I am not testing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406959/5045688

Comment: There is always a way to go around such "circular dependencies" and in most cases it is the way to go to have **testable** code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to replace a concrete dependency with a [Test Double](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html), there must be some kind of polymorphism in place. [There must be something to override or implement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1973482/126014): `abstract` or `virtual` members, or an interface.

The exception message already tells you that:

> Type to mock must be an interface, a delegate, or a non-sealed, non-static class.

It has nothing to do with whether the class in question is `internal` or `public`.

> due to some circular dependency I will not be able to use interface of this class to mock it

Nothing prevents you from using interfaces, even in the presence of circular dependencies. See e.g. [DIPPP](https://blog.ploeh.dk/dippp) for ways to deal with dependency cycles.

All that said, code will tend to be easier to maintain when it *doesn't* have circular dependencies, and when you only test against the public API.