Is C# mocking framework only limited to interfaces and virtual functions?
I started working on a C# project at work. I noticed that the Moq framework only lets you mock interfaces, virtual methods and abstract classes. Is this correct? Are the substitute frameworks which I can use to mock non-overriden methods?
Coming from Java and Python, this seems like a severe limitation where you can mock almost anything. I usually avoid modifying source code to make it more testable and so am kind of stuck as a lot of code is not built on top of interfaces.
Any advice is appreciated.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406959/5045688
