Xunit mock concrete class method
Facing error when trying to mock a Method in Concrete Class
Below is my code and the test I am trying to write for CoreException class
Inside CoreException I am calling LogMgr which is a concrete class
    public class CoreException
    {

        public CoreException()
        {

        }

        public void HandleException(string inErr)
        {
            LogMgr.Instance.Trace("", "");
        }
    }

public class LogMgr
{
    private static LogMgr mInstance = null;

    public static LogMgr Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if ((null == mInstance) )
            {
                mInstance = new LogMgr();
            }
            return mInstance;
        }
    }

    public void Trace(string logFormat, string logParams)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Log Saved");
    }
}

Below are my Unit Tests.....
namespace TestProject1
{

    public static class LogMgrMock
    {
        public static Mock<LogMgr> GetMock()
        {
            var mock = new Mock<LogMgr>();
            mock.Setup(m => m.Trace(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable();
            return mock;
        }
    }
    public class CoreExceptionTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void TestException()
        {
            var coreExec = new CoreException();
            var mockLogMgr = LogMgrMock.GetMock();
            baservException.HandleException("Test");

            mockLogMgr.Verify(m => m.Trace(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
        }
    }
}

Below is the exception Iam facing
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: m => m.Trace(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>().....  Non-overridable members (here: LogMgr.Trace) may not be used in setup / verification expressions


Don't use static. Create an interface and rewrite your logger so that it implements this interface. Then inject it into the CoreException.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406959/5045688

Well this is more of a legacy code that we are not planning to refactor.  What would be the best way to test the HandleException method ? rather than to refactor to interface

What exactly do you want to mock here? The call to Console? Generally you cannot mock a non-overridable member. However you can sometimes use other means, e.g. reflection, to get something similar. However you should do that with care, as chances are high you're testing for the internals of your system which may change. An other way would be to fake the data-source, e.g. using an in-memory database or some kind of a stream instead of a static file.

You can intercept Console.WriteLine method and test its output. See 1, 2.

Are you allowed to touch the LogMgr class -- i.e. making the Trace method virtual, and setting mInstance as protected? If yes, then we could easily mock the class, and set it as the static instance, without touching the rest of the codebase.

You can only mock a class with abstract / virtual methods, so it will not work in it's current form as a static instance.
Mock creates classes at runtime that implement interfaces or inherit from the mocked class and override / implement virtual or abstract members. It also then adds Setup / Verify functionality to those classes.
There are some commonly used logging interfaces in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions that are commonly used and have many popular implementations.
Typically they are injected in the constructor.
You are probably better using a common logging framework than rolling your own

Thanks you for the explanation, This is a legacy code and I have provided basic example to help understand the behavior.   In this case how Can I write unit tests either by not using Mocking ?  We are ok to not use Mock to have tests for this code

Short answer: you can't mock any non-overridable member. That is any static as well as any non-virtual, non-abstract and non-interface-member.
Long answer: instead of mocking specific classes in your system, you should focus on the external dependencies that you can't control. External dependenices are usually databases, files, external services and such. While you could mock your own classes as well, this tends to oversimplify your system which results in your test not representing actual test-cases. This way you test for the internals of your system instead of the external behaviour.
In your case you have an external dependency to the Console-class, which you actually should mock, but you can't, because it's static. One way to overcome this kind of problem is to focus on dependencies of your dependency until you reach some point that you can change. In your case you could change the target the Console-class  writes to:
var writer = new StringWriter();
Console.SetOut(writer);

