Context.Database.SqlQuery<Books>("select * from book") - how can you moq the Context.Database.SqlQuery method
How can you mock the
Context.Database.SqlQuery<Books>("select statement").ToList() 

statement in order to do a unit test?

Use unconstrained mocking framework. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406959/5045688

You can only replace dependencies with Test Doubles if there's some sort of polymorphism that allows that. Either the object must implement an interface, or the method must be virtual so that you can override it.
As far as I can tell, you want to replace the SqlQuery method. This method is not virtual, and neither is it part of an interface. Thus, you can't replace it with a Test Double, regardless of whether it's Moq, NSubstitute, FakeItEasy, etc.
As Alexander Petrov writes in a comment, there are frameworks that may be able to intercept a method like SqlQuery, but I'm not going to recommend that you use them, since they're likely to lead to code and tests that are difficult to maintain.
Instead, consider changing the architecture of the System Under Test so that it becomes properly testable. Whole books have been written about this topic, most famously Working Effectively with Legacy Code.
